# Cannot edit my E2 instance to N1 instance in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have stopped my instance and now I am trying to edit my instance from E2 to N1, but I am getting the following error,

> The request contains invalid arguments: "e2 instances do not support
> onHostMaintenance=TERMINATE unless they are preemptible.". Error code:
> "badRequest"

Also when I scroll down in the edit page I get these warning messages,

[image]

I am new to GCP and currently on my free trial. Please guide me on why I am not able to edit my instance from E2 to N1 and also getting these warning messages.

Note: Initially when I created my instance I created an N1 instance and then I moved to E2 instance. Now again I want to move to N1 instance and can't do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information in the question is contradictory: the error suggests that the issue is in moving to the E2 instance type (and that this didn't occur) but the text suggests that you were able to move N1-->E2 without issue.

The error is accurate, you may **not** have a E2 instance with GPUs set to Terminate that isn't also Preemptible; it must be preemptible (see links)

IIUC it **is** possible to have an N1 instance with GPUs set to Terminate that isn't preemptible; it may be preemptible.

The move to E2 should not have been permitted (which is what the error you have suggests; `badRequest`). Suggesting (!?) that you didn't actually move it to E2 and it's still N1.

However, the screenshots suggests that you're editing an E2 instance. If you weren't, you wouldn't get the warning that the "On host maintenance" isn't editable.

Can you confirm?

If you started with a Preemptible N1, the conversion should succeed (both ways).

This may be a bug with Google's service but the evidence isn't conclusive.

See [Live Migration](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration) and [Preemptible VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I can confirm that currently I am using an E2 instance. Pls check this image for proof. https://imgur.com/zJJxRob
I am getting the error message in question whenever I try to move to N1 instance. 
Also note that, when I try to change/edit the Memory or CPU in my current E2 instance itself, it doesn't give me any error and the changes happens successfully.

Comment: Yes, that does appear to confirm that there's a bug. If you have Google Support (which I assume you don't), you should ping that. Otherwise, you can file a bug using Google's Issue Tracker. Here's the link for Compute Engine bug (defects): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=1162877

Comment: If you do file an issue, please be very clear|expansive in what you did and what you experienced. If possible, start again and document each step as you do it. This will help Google reproduce the issue and understand what's going on. It may be that this is a console issue (and it *may* work using `gcloud`) but, I don't have GPU quota and can't repro for you. If you are familiar with `gcloud`, that is often a clear way to record steps as you can copy and paste commands and API responses. Best wishes!

Comment: So turns out I can contact the Google support on my free trial and I opened a case for this. They were quick in solving my issue. Don't know what the support associate did, but it solved my issue. It surely seems like a bug.